# How to explicite assign a Bean Validation (JSR303) constraint to an bean property?

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

*I use Bean Validation for Spring MVC. And Spring binds the validation failures to the bean properties where the failing annotation is defined, as well as class based constraints to the bean itself.*

My problem is that I use several class bases validation constraints, but the validation failures should not be assigned to the class but to one of the properties.

for example:

```
@ScriptAssert(lang = "javascript", script = "_this.passVerify.equals(_this.pass)")
public class MyBean {
    @Size(min=6, max=50)
    private String pass;

    private String passVerify;
}
```

(*But that is **ONLY** an **EXAMPLE**, please don't tell how I can write a custom constraint/annotation that can be put to the `pass` variable*)

What I possible need is some thing like that:

```
@ValidationAlias(
   constraint = @ScriptAssert(lang = "javascript", script = "_this.passVerify.equals(_this.pass)"),
   field = "pass")
public class MyBean {...
```

So my question is:

- Does something exist that address that issue?
- Does anybody has an better idea (I have no problem if it use spring)?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> @ValidationAlias(
>    constraint = @ScriptAssert(lang = "javascript", script = "_this.passVerify.equals(_this.pass)"),
>    field = "pass")
> public class MyBean {...
> ```

Seems to be your best bet in combination with *ConstraintValidatorContext* of  *ConstraintValidator#isValid* which allows you to customize your error message and path. Via *disableDefaultConstraintViolation* you can disable the default error message.

Comment: Did I understand you right: this is a hint how to implement the stuff?